# Posting Data Unix WebAPI using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unix

I am trying to post data to a Unix API, where it first will verify username and password, and then save the data which was sent.

The code I am using as of now is:

```
            string strUrl = string.Format("http://moktrp.com/inf0/?username=fds-           Sale003&password=CBA203&type=0&dlr=1&destination={0}&itemCode=1003);

            WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(strUrl);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream s = (Stream)response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readstream = new StreamReader(s);
            string datastring = readstream.ReadToEnd();
            response.Close();
            s.Close();
            readstream.Close();
            return true;
```

Comment: shouldn't there be a closing quote before the closing paren on your first line? Also, do you really want a bunch of spaces embedded in `username`? Good luck.

Comment: What problem are you experiencing specifically?